# PhoneGap : UIPickerView in iOS 7 does not adjust font size automatically as it does in iOS 6. Any solution for how can I achieve in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova, ios7

PhoneGap :  UIPickerView in iOS 7 does not adjust font size automatically as it does in iOS 6. Any solution for how can I achieve in iOS 7? 
[image: iOS 7 UIPickerView with Phonegap issue]

Answer (score 0):

Add `optgroup` at last and it works... :)

```
<select>
  <option selected="" disabled="">Select a value</option>
  <option>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</option>
  <option>Quirky spud boys can jam after zapping five worthy Polysixes</option>
  <option>The wizard quickly jinxed the gnomes before they vaporized</option>
  <option>All questions asked by five watched experts amaze the judge</option>
  <optgroup label=""></optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this :- [UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html)

```
You cannot customize the appearance of picker views.
```

But you can go for an alternative. You can return a custom `UILabel` in this delegate method:-

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
// Set frame, font color, font size, text, etc properties here.
return label;

}
```

Comment: This is about PhoneGap, where HTML "<select>" automatically generates pickerview within the WebView.

Comment: ok. I thought PhoneGap methods are same as iOS methods as both use same IDE i.e Xcode.